# Highcharts DateTime Localization Ukrainian

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        loading: 'Завантаження...',
        months: ['Січень', 'Лютий', 'Березень', 'Квітень', 'Травень', 'Червень', 'Липень', 'Серпень', 'Вереснь', 'Жовтень', 'Листопад', 'Грудень'],
        weekdays: ['Неділя', 'Понеділок', 'Вівторок', 'Середа', 'Четвер', 'П\'ятниця', 'Субота'],
        shortMonths: ['Січ', 'Лют', 'Бер', 'Кві', 'Тра', 'Чер', 'Лип', 'Сер', 'Вер', 'Жов', 'Лис', 'Гру'],
        exportButtonTitle: "Експорт",
        printButtonTitle: "Друкувати",
        rangeSelectorFrom: "З",
        rangeSelectorTo: "По",
        rangeSelectorZoom: "Період",
        downloadPNG: 'Скачати PNG',
        downloadJPEG: 'Скачати JPEG',
        downloadPDF: 'Скачати PDF',
        downloadSVG: 'Скачати SVG',
        printChart: 'Надрукувати графік'
    }
});
```

Ukrainian localization for Highcharts.
I searched, but could not find an answer. I hope this helps you.

Comment: There is no question anywhere.

Comment: You can ask question and answer yourself. This looks like answer post only.